# How to Update Clock Time To UTC TIME in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-pub

I used a flutter package called analog clock - [link here](https://pub.dev/packages/analog_clock) to create a clock. I don't want to use Datetime.now but want to use a UTC time of +3. I've tweaked the UTC code a couple of times but still don't know to make it work with this package. There seems to be a bug with the package.
In my code I changed the date time to

- DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(hours: 3)), to show UTC +3.
  However, whenever I run the app, the clock keeps showing the current daytime now. I've tried tweaking the code but cant fix

Here is my code where I call the analog clock package

```
class TimeAndWeatherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context)
        .size; //this gonna give us total height and with of our device
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // Here the height of the container is 45% of our total height
            height: size.height * .50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 10),
                    child: Center(
                        child: TitleText(
                      text: "time",
                    )),
                  ),
                  CurrentDate(),
                  Center(
                    child: AnalogClock(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor, width: 0.5),
                        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                            blurRadius: 2.0,
                            spreadRadius: 0.0,
                            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      width: 270.0,
                      height: 400,
                      isLive: true,
                      showTicks: true,
                      showAllNumbers: true,
                      showDigitalClock: true,
                      showNumbers: true,
                      showSecondHand: true,
                      hourHandColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                      minuteHandColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                      secondHandColor: Color(0xB35FD245),
                      numberColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                      textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      digitalClockColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                      datetime:
                          DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(hours: 3)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the original code of the package

```
class AnalogClock extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime datetime;
  final bool showDigitalClock;
  final bool showTicks;
  final bool showNumbers;
  final bool showAllNumbers;
  final bool showSecondHand;
  final Color hourHandColor;
  final Color minuteHandColor;
  final Color secondHandColor;
  final Color tickColor;
  final Color digitalClockColor;
  final Color numberColor;
  final bool isLive;
  final double textScaleFactor;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final BoxDecoration decoration;

  const AnalogClock(
      {this.datetime,
      this.showDigitalClock = true,
      this.showTicks = true,
      this.showNumbers = true,
      this.showSecondHand = true,
      this.showAllNumbers = false,
      this.hourHandColor = Colors.black,
      this.minuteHandColor = Colors.black,
      this.secondHandColor = Colors.redAccent,
      this.tickColor = Colors.grey,
      this.digitalClockColor = Colors.black,
      this.numberColor = Colors.black,
      this.textScaleFactor = 1.0,
      this.width = double.infinity,
      this.height = double.infinity,
      this.decoration = const BoxDecoration(),
      isLive,
      Key key})
      : this.isLive = isLive ?? (datetime == null),
        super(key: key);

  const AnalogClock.dark(
      {datetime,
      showDigitalClock = true,
      showTicks = true,
      showNumbers = true,
      showAllNumbers = false,
      showSecondHand = true,
      width = double.infinity,
      height = double.infinity,
      decoration = const BoxDecoration(),
      Key key})
      : this(
            datetime: datetime,
            showDigitalClock: showDigitalClock,
            showTicks: showTicks,
            showNumbers: showNumbers,
            showAllNumbers: showAllNumbers,
            showSecondHand: showSecondHand,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            hourHandColor: Colors.white,
            minuteHandColor: Colors.white,
            secondHandColor: Colors.redAccent,
            tickColor: Colors.grey,
            digitalClockColor: Colors.white,
            numberColor: Colors.white,
            decoration: decoration,
            key: key);

  @override
  _AnalogClockState createState() => _AnalogClockState(datetime);
}

class _AnalogClockState extends State<AnalogClock> {
  DateTime datetime;

  _AnalogClockState(datetime) : this.datetime = datetime ?? DateTime.now();

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.isLive) {
      // update clock every second or minute based on second hand's visibility.
      Duration updateDuration =
          widget.showSecondHand ? Duration(seconds: 1) : Duration(minutes: 1);
      Timer.periodic(updateDuration, update);
    }
  }

  update(Timer timer) {
    if (mounted) {
      // update is only called on live clocks. So, it's safe to update datetime.
      datetime = DateTime.now();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      decoration: widget.decoration,
      child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1.0,
              child: new Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 48.0, minHeight: 48.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: new CustomPaint(
                    painter: new AnalogClockPainter(
                        datetime: datetime,
                        showDigitalClock: widget.showDigitalClock,
                        showTicks: widget.showTicks,
                        showNumbers: widget.showNumbers,
                        showAllNumbers: widget.showAllNumbers,
                        showSecondHand: widget.showSecondHand,
                        hourHandColor: widget.hourHandColor,
                        minuteHandColor: widget.minuteHandColor,
                        secondHandColor: widget.secondHandColor,
                        tickColor: widget.tickColor,
                        digitalClockColor: widget.digitalClockColor,
                        textScaleFactor: widget.textScaleFactor,
                        numberColor: widget.numberColor),
                  )))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the update() method in your library, it won't use your timezone, actually, it does not even accept a timezone parameter so it cannot even know what to use. To me it seems that what you're looking for is not supported by the library.

Comment: is there anyway to edit this so I can manually set it to the timezone I want

Comment: @EmmyA The `update` is of his own making. It's not part of the library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a few things going on here.

1. You should be updating the `datetime` property *within* the `setState` call:

```dart
update(Timer timer) {
  if (!mounted) return;

  setState(() => datetime = DateTime.now());
}
```

2. You're updating the time without setting the timezone again, which would revert it to your local time. So the above should look like this:

```dart
update(Timer timer) {
  if (!mounted) return;

  setState(() => datetime = DateTime.now().toUtc());
  // Or to an arbitrary time in the future, if that's what you need:
  // setState(() => datetime = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(hours: 3)));
}
```

Aside from that...

- You should store a reference to the timer, so you can `cancel()` it in the widget's `dispose()` method.
- Note that you are only updating the "mode" of the clock (seconds, or minutes) in the `initState` method of your widget, which only gets called once in the lifetime of a widget. It doesn't get called again when the widget is updated. For that you need to use `didUpdateWidget`.

### OR...

I highly recommend you check out the [Riverpod package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod), as it makes state management a lot easier. For example, the above code could look something like this...

```dart
final clockProvider = StateProvider<DateTime>((ref) => DateTime.now().toUtc());

class CustomClock extends ConsumerWidget{
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return AnalogClock(
      ...
      datetime: ref.watch(clockProvder),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class ClockModeButton extends ConsumerWidget{
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return TextButton(
      ...
      onPressed: () {
        final DateTime newDateTime = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(hours: 3));
        ref.read(clockPrivder.notifier).state = newDateTime;
      },
      ...
    );
  }
}
```